# Understanding the notation of a paper

Tags: number-theory, notation, algebraic-number-theory

I am reading a paper on Algebraic Number Theory that says

> If $p$ divides the discriminant of polynomial $f$ $r$ times and there is the factorization into irreducibles $$f(x)\equiv g_1(x)\dots g_r(x)\pmod{p^{r+1}}$$ then for $s\geq r+1$, $$f(x)\equiv g_1^{(s)}(x)\dots g_r^{(s)}(x)\pmod{p^{s}}$$

I am having trouble understanding what $g^{(s)}(x)$ may mean here, as it obviously does not mean derivative.

Comment: It's just saying that if you can factor $f$ into $r$ irreducibles modulo $p^{r+1}$ then you can also factor $f$ into $r$ polynomials for any higher $p$-power modulus..The $g_i^{(s)}$ are just names..

Answer (score 1):

It is just an index. It means, that for any $s \geq r+1$, such a factorization exists and the factors are called $g_i^{(s)}$, since they of course depend on $s$.

Comment: Thank you! So this is just Hensel's lemma right?

Comment: Yes, you are right.